# VBA Excel Find all rows that don't fit the requirements of the sequence and clear

Tags: excel, vba

I am very much a beginner in coding and I am trying to write a macro for a large data set at the request of my company. So the data set is much larger than the below screenshot but I am trying to write a macro that will look at the Rep column and add a blank row for Panelists who's rep ends before 5. So for each panelist/screening combo I need it to be able to identify the sequences (0-5) that end before 5. I have searched the internet for weeks to figure out how/where to start writing this. I am hoping to get some guidance on ways I can approach writing this.  [image: Sample Data Set]

Comment: Post your desired result please including more than one panelist/screening combo

Comment: Loop the rows and look for zeros in ColE where the cell above is not 5

Comment: Do you dispose of version MS 365? @daniel1234

Answer (score 0):

This below code will add a row after every set that does not have 5 reps.

```
Sub Test()

Dim RepRow, LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet1

RepRow = 2  ' Set this to whatever row your data starts on

Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & RepRow))

    If Range("E" & RepRow).Value - Range("E" & RepRow + 1).Value > 0 And Range("E" & RepRow).Value < 5 Then

    Range("A" & RepRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert

    RepRow = RepRow + 2

    End If

    RepRow = RepRow + 1

Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You will still have to update the `E` in the above code to whatever column the reps are in and possibly the `A` to another column with data.

Comment: May I know what you are specifically looking for? This code will need editing in order for it to do exactly what you want. Not sure why it's downvoted.

Comment: So the sequence for Rep column should go 0,1,2,3,4,5 for each panelist/screening/site combo. This is data collected from an instrument so sometimes we only get 4 Reps for a site on a particular panelist so I am looking to find those panelists in the data set

Comment: So you're specifically looking for the sets with only 4 panelists?

Comment: I am looking for panelists with less than 5 reps

Comment: @daniel1234 this above code should insert a row after every set that does not have 5 reps.  You may have to update some columns/rows but for the sample data table supplied this works

Answer (score 0):

### Insert Blank Rows

- It is assumed that the data 'nicely' starts in cell `A1` and has one row of headers and has no empty rows or columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertBefore0()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(5)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    
    For r = 3 To rg.Rows.Count
        Set cCell = crg.Cells(r)
        If cCell.Value = 0 Then
            If cCell.Offset(-1).Value < 5 Then
                If drg Is Nothing Then ' combine cells into a range
                    Set drg = cCell.Offset(, m)
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, cCell.Offset(, m))
                End If
                m = (m + 1) Mod 2 ' prevent two consecutive rows inserted
            End If
        End If
    Next r
        
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    drg.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
    MsgBox "Blank rows inserted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```